# (uncaught exception)TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, uncaught-exception

I have the following code to try to save the URL file temporarily and then call it in a test, I am using selectFile command from cypress.
cy.get('input[type="file"]').selectFile({
contents: fileType
}, { force: true }
});

but I get the error:
**TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function**

I added const fs = require('fs');

```
getFile (format, directory = 'files', url = null) {
    if (!url) {
        url = 'https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file_example_PNG_500kB.png';
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, `/../../tmp/${directory}`);
        const filePath = path.join(directoryPath, `/file.${format}`);
        // Check if the file already exists
        if (!fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
            getBuffer(url).then((buffer) => {
                fs.mkdirSync(directoryPath, { recursive: true });
                // Save the file
                fs.writeFile(filePath, buffer, 'binary', () => {
                    resolve(filePath);
                });
            });
        } else {
            resolve(filePath);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: None of the other [fs.existsSync is not a function](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=fs.existsSync+is+not+a+function+site%3Astackoverflow.com) questions had an answer for you?

Comment: You don't have another var called `fs` in that unit by any chance do you?

Comment: I searched and tried to use the answer for the others' posts, but I couldn't fix the error. @Andreas

Comment: I don't have another call @Keith

Comment: Could you try `import * as fs from "fs"`, nodeJS has two different module loaders now, and I'm not sure how `require` works in ES module loading mode.

Comment: I tried, but it is not working @Keith

Comment: Obviously `fs` exists, otherwise you'd get another error, what does `console.log(fs)` show?

Comment: Oh, hang on a tick.  cypress SelectFile is a browser thing, not a node side.. You can't use `fs.existsSync` on the browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250842/discussion-between-ealvarado-and-keith).

Comment: `Cypress is a next generation front end testing tool built for the modern web.`...    Node is back end..

Comment: So, I'm guessing that you're bundling this and trying to run it in the browser.  There is no access to the `fs` module when run in the browser.  That is something that only exists in nodejs on the server.